# Connecting to my private cosmos DB using Python code

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have set up a private azure cosmos DB which wold have a private endpoint in my private subnet. I have also added firewall rules to my cosmosdb so all subnets (including public subnet) can access to my cosmos db. However, I can not connect to my comsos DB through python codes even through my private subnet which had the private endpoint to cosmosdb:

```
>>> from azure.cosmosdb.table import TableService
>>> the_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****account;AccountKey=****==;TableEndpoint=https://****.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/;"
>>> service=TableService(endpoint_suffix = "table.cosmos.azure.com", connection_string= the_connection_string)
>>> service.get_table_service_stats()
```

I got below error

```
Client-Request-ID=79d43c5a-e071-11ea-b2d1-***** Retry policy did not allow for a retry: , HTTP status code=Unknown, Exception=HTTPSConnectionPool(host='*****.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?restype=service&comp=stats (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd6f13fcf90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')).
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I think this is motly related to DocuentDB and authorization headers..so my core need a bit more refinemnts perhaps and it is not related to my network..

Comment: Can you connect your cosmos DB vai storage explorer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows

Comment: Yes, I can connect through it..

Comment: Please try to just provide connection string to connect the cosmos db?